# Python Dataframe logical operations with two If statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a big data frame with float values. I want to perform two if logical operations.

My code:

```
df = 
    A     
0  78.5  
1  54
2  48
3  21.1

# I want to compare 'A' data with predefined limits and assign a rank.
# Give rank 1 if > 70, 2 if 70< > 40, 3 if < 40
# create a new df with limits
adf = pd.DataFrame({'A_up':[70],'A_low':[40]})
# repeat adf to match df size
adf = adf.loc[adf.index.repeat(len(df))]

# perform the logical operation
df['A_op'] = np.where((df['A']>adf['A_up'].values),1, 2)
df['A_op'] = np.where((df['A']<adf['A_low'].values),3, 2)
```

Present output

```
df = 
    A     A_op
0  78.5   2
1  54     2
2  48     2
3  21.1   3
```

Expected output

```
df = 
    A     A_op
0  78.5   1
1  54     2
2  48     2
3  21.1   3
```

Comment: what if `df['A']` is 70?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try via [`np.select()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
conditions=[
    df['A'].gt(70),
    df['A'].lt(70) & df['A'].gt(40),
    df['A'].lt(40)
]

labels=[1,2,3]
```

Finally:

```
df['A_op']=np.select(conditions,labels)
```

**Note:** Since you don't specify the condition for `df['A']==40` and `df['A']==70`

but if you wish for

```
#df['A']==40--->3
#df['A']==70--->2
```

Then the above solution becomes:

```
conditions=[
    df['A'].gt(70),
    df['A'].le(70) & df['A'].gt(40),
    df['A'].le(40)
]

labels=[1,2,3]

df['A_op']=np.select(conditions,labels)
```

Output of `df`:

```
    A       A_op
0   78.5    1
1   54.0    2
2   48.0    2
3   21.1    3
```

Comment: `np.select` is actually the correct answer to my situation. I realized lately. Please, see the new question and answer I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135242/python-dataframe-logical-operations-on-multiple-columns-using-multiple-if-statem

Answer (score 2):

Seems like [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut) would work:

```
import numpy as np

df['A_op'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=[np.NINF, 40, 70, np.inf], labels=[3, 2, 1])
```

`df`:

```
      A A_op
0  78.5    1
1  54.0    2
2  48.0    2
3  21.1    3
```

Comment: For me, this is the best approach.

Comment: Can this be applied if there is one more column `B` and its own limits `B_low`, `B_up`. Because, my actual df has many float columns.

Comment: Not really, other than individually calling `cut` on each column. Programmatically extracting the bounds is doable. But that is a _very_ different question than the one you've posed here and involves a non-trivial amount of logic to align the bounds and rank. That should probably be a separate question about ranking `n` columns based on a separate `DataFrame` of bounds (or something similar).

Comment: Thanks. Here is a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135242/python-dataframe-logical-operations-on-multiple-columns-using-multiple-if-statem

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the following way:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 70:
        return 1
    elif 40 < x < 70:
        return 2
    elif x < 40:
        return 3

df['A_op'] = [f(i) for i in df['A']]
```

Also what about if x=40 or x=70?